# Twitter bootstrap datetime picker not co-operating with MySQL

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a view, like this:

```
<div class="input-append date the_date">
    <input data-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="text" readonly>
</div>
```

and js, like this:

```
var the_date = $('.the_date > input').val();
// [DATA FOR SERVER]:
var data={ the_date : the_date }
```

And when I submit the date form, the data array is sent to a controller which inserts the date via a model function.

However the selected date is NOT inserted to the database.

I can alert(the_date); from js, I can echo $the_date; from the controller and I can even echo $the_date; from the model, however $the_date does not go into the database.

I have a standard datetime field in MySQL called the_date which has the standard MySQL datetime format of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", and I can't figure out why the_date is not going into the db.

I am using CodeIgniter's Active Record for inserts, and every other insert works fine.
I can insert dates with:

```
'the_date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

for example, and I can also say:

```
'the_date' => '2002-11-11 12:12:12')
```

But the default datetime of "0000-00-00 00:00:00" is inserted everytime I use the datetimepicker from Bootstrap....

Comment: You'll need to share more code than this. You haven't even shown your controller code, or the Javascript code for making the request.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cryode said, you have to give more code than that..

Im assuming the_date is a string of format '2002-11-11 12:12:12'. 
Have you tried something like:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(the_date))
```